# Delegator through BasicObject transparency

Tags: ruby, delegates, decorator

**Context**: I am trying to put up a Decorator pattern in Ruby. As a Decorator should delegate all unknown methods to the underlying objects, I used the Delegator class. 
I could have used SimpleDelegator but I wanted to fully understand what I was doing.

So the basic code I came out with was :

```
class Decorator < Delegator
  def initialize(component)
    super
    @component = component
  end

  def __setobj__(o); @component = o   end
  def __getobj__;    @component       end
  def send(s, *a);   __send__(s, *a)  end
end
```

Which is ~exactly the same as the implementation of SimpleDelegator. Seems good.

But the thing I did not want was for the code handling the Decorator to know it is manipulating a Decorator. I want full transparency.

At this moment `Decorator.new(Object.new).class` returned `Decorator`

So I tinkered a bit and came up with this :

```
class Decorator < Delegator
  undef_method :==
  undef_method :class
  undef_method :instance_of?

  # Stores the decorated object
  def initialize(component)
    super
    @component = component
  end

  def __setobj__(o); @component = o   end
  def __getobj__;    @component       end
  def send(s, *a);   __send__(s, *a)  end
end
```

This way, I can safely use `class` or `instance_of?` on my Decorated object, it will send the method to the underlying object via method_missing (which is implemented by Delegator).

The thing is : I don't understand why I had to undef `:class` and `:instance_of?`. I can see that BasicObject defines `:==` so I had to undefine it but what about those two ?
I looked at the BasicObject documentation and a bit in the C code but did not find anything. I looked the same at the Delegator documentation and code, and did not find anything either.
It seems Delegator include the Kernel module, but Kernel#class or Kernel#instance_of? don't  exist.

Where those two method came from ? Why did I need to undefine them if they were not implemented at all ?
I guess I must be missing something about Ruby's object model or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a hint by inspecting the method:

```
Decorator.instance_method(:class)
  # =>  #<UnboundMethod: Decorator(#<Module:0x00000102137498>)#class>
```

The method's owner is `Decorator` but actually defined in `#<Module:0x00000102137498>`. So there is an anonymous module that defines it. Interesting... let's look at:

```
Decorator.ancestors
  # => [Decorator, Delegator, #<Module:0x00000102137498>, BasicObject]
```

There's that module again, between `Delegator` and `BasicObject`. So `Delegator` doesn't directly derive from `BasicObject`. If you look at the source code in `lib/delegate.rb` you find:

```
class Delegator < BasicObject
  kernel = ::Kernel.dup
  kernel.class_eval do
    [:to_s,:inspect,:=~,:!~,:===,:<=>,:eql?,:hash].each do |m|
      undef_method m
    end
  end
  include kernel
  # ...
```

So a copy of the `Kernel` module is made, which doesn't have `to_s`, `inspect`, etc... but still has `class` and `instance_of?`. It's included in `Delegator` and that's where they come from.

Note that `Object` inherits the same methods by including the `Kernel` module (but it includes the full module, of course):

```
42.method(:class) # => #<Method: Fixnum(Kernel)#class>
```

This is stated in the [`Object` doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html):

> Object mixes in the Kernel module, making the built-in kernel
>   functions globally accessible. Although the instance methods of Object
>   are defined by the Kernel module, we have chosen to document them here
>   for clarity.

Comment: So you're saying that `class` & `instance_of?` comes from the Kernel Module ? I can't find those methods in the Kernel module documentation Oo : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html . Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I'll add a line to the Kernel doc to state this too.